# Using schedule to do a task until a certain time?

Tags: python

So basically I am using schedule to run a task every hour. The function (or job) which I schedule to run every hour I want to stop at a certain time. The function checks the price of a stock and I want to check the price every hour but only until 5:00 pm which is the time that the market closes. Using the prices when the stock market opens and closes I want to find certain numbers like amount increase and percent change and etc. So how can I schedule to run a function from a start point to an endpoint. Such as 8:00 am to 5:00 pm while checking every hour?

Comment: Schedule to task to start running at the desire start time, and have it schedule another run of _itself_ if the current time is less than the cutoff time.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a scheduling library such as [schedule](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/)

```
import time
import schedule

def check_price():
    ...

schedule.every().day.at("8:00").do(check_price)
schedule.every().day.at("9:00").do(check_price)
schedule.every().day.at("10:00").do(check_price)
...

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: yes! this is similar to what I am using but I am using schedule.every().hour.do(check_stock_price) to check the price every hour but I did not know that you can use that and also enter a specific time! That solves my problem instantly! Also I have one more question, is the time the ("8:00"), ("9:00") and ("10:00") in 24-hour time? Or in my case for example where I want the time to be 8:00 am and 5:00 pm I can just do it that way. Also if it isn't 24 hour then how do we make it so that ("8:00") refers to 8:00 am and not 8:00 pm?

Comment: @JackJones I belief it is a 24 hour clock.

Comment: cool! Also can I not test it with the time I have currently? Like its 7:17 so can I not change the time to 19:17 and then test it? Or once I run it, the next day and for every day it will check at 19:17?

Comment: @JackJones you probably can change the system time to trigger the job. But while testing your code you might want to schedule your job more frequently so you dont have to wait. I recommend reading the [docs](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for what you can and can't do. If this answers your question, can you mark it as such?

Comment: yeah I could, this current trigger is perfect as it checks it every single day which is what I want it to do but I will just leave it and then run it tomorrow and see if it does run the job at that specific time.